# EXPIRY OF ABANDONED CART

Tags: magento2.3, abandoned-cart

Is there any configuration to control the expiry of abandoned cart in the admin section in abandoned cart report?
thank you

Comment: You mean you want to remove to remove abandoned carts after certain time?

Comment: right! is there any configuration in the admin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called managing [quote lifetime](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/cart-quote-lifetime.html).

There is a configuration in admin panel at **Stores => Configuration => Sales => Checkout => Shopping cart => Quote Lifetime (days)**

Here by default it is set to 30 days which means quotes which were not updated in last 30 days will be removed.

The cronjob `sales_clean_quotes` which calls method `\Magento\Sales\Cron\CleanExpiredQuotes::execute` will remove these quotes from the database. Please note that it will not be only removed from abandoned cart report, these items will be removed from the customers cart as well according to the configured quote lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for your response, if I understand well, if I change Quote Lifetime (days) to 2 per example, I will lost the abandoned cart report in 2 days, right?

Comment: Yes. Also, customers will not see items in cart if he has not updated cart (add/edit/remove item) in last 2 days.